# How to solve dependency Injections using Moq and xUnit testing in .Net Core 6 application

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, xunit

I am working on an application where I need to test some of my services. The problem is that I have other dependencies in my service manager. When ever I run the test the result always comes null. Here is my implementation.

> XUnit

```
public class UnitTest1
    {
        private readonly Mock<IDadJokeService> _dadJokeService;
        public UnitTest1()
        {
            _dadJokeService = new Mock<IDadJokeService>();
        }
           public async void GetDadJoke()
    {
        // Arrange
        var jokeController = new JokeController(_dadJokeService.Object);
        this._dadJokeService.Setup(c => c.GetJokeAsync()).ReturnsAsync(GetDadJokesData());
        // Act
        var result = await jokeController.Get();

        // Assert
        Assert.NotNull(result);
    }

    private JokeResponseViewModel GetDadJokesData()
    {
        JokeResponseViewModel jokeData = new JokeResponseViewModel
        {
            id= "218xkq49prc",
            joke = "A termite walks into a bar and asks “Is the bar tender here?”",
            status = 200
        };
        return jokeData;
    }

    }
```

> Controller

```
  [ApiController]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class JokeController : BaseController
{

    private readonly IDadJokeService _dadJokeService;
  
    public JokeController(IDadJokeService dadJokeService)
    {
        this._dadJokeService = dadJokeService;
    }
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<GenericResponseModel> Get()
    {
        var response = await _dadJokeService.GetJokeAsync();
        if (response?.status == (int)HttpStatusCode.OK)
            return ApiResponse(response, response.status, true, "Success!");
        else
            return ApiResponse(null, (int)HttpStatusCode.NotFound,  false, "No Joke Found!");
    }

}
```

> ServiceManager

```
 public class DadJokeService : IDadJokeService
    {
        private readonly IHttpCallerService _httpCallerService;
        private readonly IMemoryCache _cache;
        public DadJokeService(IHttpCallerService httpCallerService, IMemoryCache cache)
        {
            this._httpCallerService = httpCallerService;
            this._cache = cache;
        }
        public async Task<JokeResponseViewModel?> GetJokeAsync()
        {
            var response = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<JokeResponseViewModel>(await _httpCallerService.GetRequestAsync());
            return response;
        }

    }
```

The result in UnitTest is always null. From Service Manager I am calling an Http request which returns my random results.

Comment: Can you provide some interfaces and implementation methods you use? I tested your code, but the result is not null.

Answer (score 0):

Your `JokeController.Get()` calls `JokeService.GetJokeAsync`. You do the right thing by mocking the `JokeService` and you already pass it to the tested object (controller).

The only think missing is the setup for the methods that are called on the mock object (without this you will get a `null`).

Add to your test method:

```
var myExpectedTestResult = new JokeResponseViewModel();
this._dadJokeService.Setup(c => c.GetJokeAsync()).ReturnsAsync(myExpectedTestResult);
```

So you create the JokeResponseViewModel in the test code directly, without calling the `JokesService`. This provides the testing isolation (you test your controller without having to worry if your service works right or not).

That's the whole idea about mocking: you mock the dependency by creating a mock object, than you `Setup` what the calls to this mock will return. You can have different setups based on the parameters you pass etc.

Sometime the only thing you want to check (test) if a specific method was invoked on your mock object.

[moq docu](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart) can also be helpful.

Comment: The expected response is basically a random result which can't be static that is why I am facing an issue.  One thing more I am facing an null error on **JsonSerializer.Deserialize** too.

Comment: In your test, the code of JokeService should never be called, because you are testing JokeController. That's why you mock to test in isolation. If you want to test JokeService (and deserialization) you will write a new test and mock that service dependencies (memory cache and HTTP caller service). Also updated the answer to make the idea of mocked returned value to be clearer.

Comment: and what about expected result I am calling an API which always return a new result set so that is why I am unable to define any expected result and my response in Controller is always **null**.

Comment: If I added expectedResult it will always return an object with empty data.

Comment: You should be able to define the expected result, in fact several: one test with a ViewModel with result=OK to test the ok path (in this case you assert it's not null and probably some fields), another test with not OK (you test your controller's ability to react to errors in the service and provide sensible output). Think about it like this: you mock a dependency and setup a method. When test runs, not your real method is executed, but the set up version of it. Like this you can easily mock the results of the dependencies and concentrate on testing one class (in your case - controller).

Comment: Please see the updated question for UnitTest class

Comment: Here status code will be same if the API runs successfully and id and joke will always be different.